# Cucumber error - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider`

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber-java

Im getting this error while running a very basic feature file in Eclipse through Selenium in Java

`Exception in thread"main"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider`

Im using the following jars

`cucumber-java-4.3.0` , `cucumber-core-4.3.0` , `gherkin-6.0.17` and `junit-4.12`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your version of Gherkin doesn't match the one Cucumber 4.3.0 is using; replace it with `gherkin-5.1.0`. (See the [pom.xml](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/pom.xml).)

In general, I'd recommend using a dependency manager (Maven or Gradle) to make sure you are getting the correct transitive dependencies. You can find which dependencies you need for Cucumber in the [installation docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/).

Answer (score 1):

Please remove **cucumber-core**, **cucumber-java**, **gherkin** and **Junit**. They're transitive dependencies and will be provided by your dependencies.(You can add below set of dependency)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```